# Maximizing Speed on an Elliptical Path

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, physics, parametric, kinematics

I'm currently delving into a problem that involves analyzing the motion of a particle moving along an elliptical path in the plane, and I could really use some help figuring out a couple of aspects. The motion of the particle is defined by the position vector $$\mathbf{r}(t)=(3 \cos 2 \pi t, 2 \sin 2 \pi t),$$ where (t) represents the time in seconds since the particle started moving. Here are the specifics I'm wrestling with:

a) **Identifying Points of Maximum Speed**: I understand that the speed of a particle is the magnitude of its velocity vector, which can be found by differentiating the position vector with respect to time. However, I'm stuck on figuring out how to use this information to determine the exact points on the elliptical path where the speed of the particle reaches its maximum. How can I identify these points?

b) **Calculating Maximum Speed**: Once the points of maximum speed are known, how can I calculate the exact value of this maximum speed? I presume it involves evaluating the speed at the identified points, but I'm unsure how to proceed with the calculations.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Differentiating the position vector to obtain the velocity vector.
- Attempting to calculate the magnitude of this velocity vector to find the speed.

However, I'm not confident in my approach to identifying where this speed is maximized and would greatly appreciate any guidance or step-by-step explanation on how to tackle parts (a) and (b) of this problem.

Comment: Maximize the length of the velocity vector with respect to $t$. Then use that value of $t$ to find the points you want.

Comment: The speed magnitude is the norm of the speed vector $\sqrt{x't)^2+y'(t)^2}$

Comment: @CyclotomicField My challenge lies in the specifics of dealing with the expressions for velocity derived from the given position vector $\mathbf{r}(t) = (3\cos(2\pi t), 2\sin(2\pi t))$. After differentiation, the velocity vector contains components with $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, each multiplied by different coefficients due to the elliptical path, resulting in the speed formula being $\sqrt{(-6\pi \sin(2\pi t))^2 + (4\pi \cos(2\pi t))^2}$.

Comment: My primary issue is how to approach the problem of finding the maximum speed when inside the square root, I have $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ terms with different weights (coefficients). I'm not entirely sure how to analytically determine the maximum of the speed given this mix of terms and their respective weights. Any further guidance on tackling this specific aspect would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @tarekhankir to find the maxima and minima of a real function $f(t)$ use that $f'(t)=0$ to find candidate solutions. You may want to use that $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is maximized at the same point where $f(x)$ is maximized.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I am not sure how, could you explain please?

Comment: If $s(t)$ is the speed at time $t$, @CyclotomicField is suggesting working with $s^2(t)$ instead. It’s a good idea.